# In WCF, should you have large MaxBufferPoolSize value for large messages?

Tags: wcf, performance

For this WCF service I have developed, I have to set MaxReceivedMessageSize to 5MB. My current problem is figuring out whether it is better to have a larger MaxBufferPoolSize value, like 5MB, or retain the original 512KB value.

Does anyone knows what is the recommended setting for this scenario?
In short, should I set MaxBufferPoolSize = 5242880 (5MB), or MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288 (512KB)?

**UPDATE:** For clarification, the service is meant to insert a new customer record along with some scanned documents. As a result, the message size may reached up to 5MB.

We *could* try and separate the upload of the scanned document using alternate technologies, but the requirement was both customer record and scanned documents must be in the same transaction, so we decided to go with this approach, until we figure out how to use WCF's transaction capability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out this article.
http://kennyw.com/?p=51

It suggests setting the MaxBufferPoolSize to zero for large messages in order to avoid buffering.

Comment: Thanks for answering this old question, that's the sort of information that could help.

Comment: What does it mean 'for large messages' - the pool size is for the whole service, right?

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly OK to transfer large amounts of data to a WCF-based service, but you should look into a binding that supports streaming instead of buffered transfers (BasicHttpBinding or a CustomBinding) so each service instance doesn't hog too much memory.

--larsw

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to transfer files and such, this seems like your only option.  Otherwise I'd review why such large pieces of data are being sent across the service in the first place.  If it is files and such, you'll just have to live with that large size and the possible repercussions.  You also, again if it is files you're moving, might want to try an FTP component or something instead.

I could provide more information with a little elaboration.  I'll check back later to see if you've added anything to your question.

Answer (score -4):

5 Mb seems like a lot of data to transfer over a Web Service.
The first thing you should look for is to send less data.
Secondly you need to set the size to your needs.

Comment: Remember that WCF can be used for more than simple web services.