# WCF Streaming System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: vb.net, wcf, streaming, out-of-memory

In my streamed WCF application I get `System.OutOfMemoryExceptions` in my service for large messages (querying >7GB MSSQL tables using a datareader, messages might even exceed 7GB) while small messages work just fine. I can observe the memory usage grow constantly during the execution of `DataReaderToExcelXml` (see below). The weird thing is, that it usually grows fast to 2GB, stays at 2GB +-1GB for a while (1-5 minutes) and then again raises very fast to ~6.5GB which leads to the exception (machine has 8GB memory). At this point it looks to me, as if the Stream isn't passed through anymore but buffered.

I already enabled trace logging, but it seems to stop with the exception. The `DataReaderToExcelXml` function call is the last visible event in the trace log.

In the WCF message contract I ensured that the message only contains the Stream. On client side, the returned Stream is simply read, written to a filestream and disposed. However, I can never observe the client code being executed or the file being written when I get the exception.

I already tried setting the `maxBufferPoolSize` to zero, both on the client and server side, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/595871/4166885. No success.

Stream writer function on WCF-service side:

```
 Public Shared Function DataReaderToExcelXml(ByRef dr As SqlDataReader) As Stream
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream
    Dim tw As New IO.StreamWriter(ms)

    For Each row As DbDataRecord In dr
            'Embed row in ExcelXml, detailed function omitted
            tw.write(row.toString()) 'row.toString is just a simplification
    End While

    tw.Flush()
    dr.Close()
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

    Return ms
 End Function
```

Web.config bindings

```
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding receiveTimeout="24.00:00:00" sendTimeout="24.00:00:00"
          maxBufferPoolSize="9223372036854775807" maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807"
          messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="Streamed" bypassProxyOnLocal="True">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

App.config bindings

```
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="24.00:00:00" sendTimeout="24.00:00:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="8589934592" messageEncoding="Mtom"
        textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
    </binding>
```

edit: Using .NET memory profiler on my service I found out, that the increasing amount of memory can be traced back to the type `byte[]`. Personally, that's not telling anything to me, but maybe it's useful information.

edit2: While inspecting the `System.OutOfMemoryException` I just noticed that it occurs when ms.Capacity = ms.length = 1073741824 = 1GB. So just before the memory stream would double its capacity. I'm still not sure, why w3wp consumes such large amounts of memory in the first place, but now it's clear that the memory stream triggers the Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, reading your question, I think that the source of your error, is the key. Where is exactly the error? In transport, or in your server? 
If the Exception is raised in DataReaderToExcel, maybe you could consider another ideas (I think it isn't a WCF issue):
By now, I think you would have the same problem in a Windows forms app.

You need memory, so you can fill it only with your SqlDataReader, you have to query by blocks,  based on ranges.

We will start computing the "TotalRecords":

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM YOUR_TABLE  
WHERE WATHEVER_YOU_WANT
```

For example, querying blocks of **10.000** records, you have TotalRecords/10.000 pages (querys) +1. (Example: 30.001 rows, 10.000 row per block = 4 queries )

Iterate building them so:

```
select top **10.000** * from 
(SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YOUR_TABLE_FIELD_1 DESC) ROW_PAGINATED, YOUR_TABLE_FIELD_1, YOUR_TABLE_FIELD_2 , ... , YOUR_TABLE_FIELD_N 
FROM YOUR_TABLE  
WHERE WATHEVER_YOU_WANT 
ORDER BY YOUR_TABLE_FIELD_1 DESC
) YOUR_ALIAS
WHERE YOUR_ALIAS.ROW_PAGINATED BETWEEN min_records_per_page AND max_records_per_page 
)
```

Where  min_records_per_page AND max_records_per_page have this values:

```
Query 1:
  min_records_per_page= 1  
  max_records_per_page  = 10000
Query 2:
  min_records_per_page= 10001  
  max_records_per_page  = 20000
  ...
 Query N:
  min_records_per_page= (N-1)* +1
  max_records_per_page  = TotalRecords
```

On each iteration, you will map each datarow into a ExcelXml class.

Doing so, you will avoid to consume all the memory, assuming you will be Disposing the objects you use. You can use the Function SetProcessWorkingSetSize each 2 iterations, for example.
To free memory after a significant number of processed rows:

```
Private Declare Auto Function SetProcessWorkingSetSize Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal procHandle As IntPtr, ByVal min As Int32, ByVal max As Int32) As Boolean

 Dim Mem As Process
 Mem = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
 SetProcessWorkingSetSize(Mem.Handle, -1, -1)
```

Then, now you have an array with mapped objects. Part 1 finished.

Part 2. Your client WCF may receive this data. Tell us then if you have problems once the data to be sent are ready. Then we can explore communication parameters, and then we would say "increase that parameter, or add this one".

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in your 1st sentence. When I attach w3wp.exe to debugger the exception is raised at tw.write() in DataReaderToExcel. "Using tw" doesn't change anything. 1) I don't see where I can use dispose or set to nothing, because tw is my only object. 2) In case I'll do that, could you elaborate? Do you mean partitioning the query into multiple smaller queries? So manual buffering in a way? 3) At first it seemed to work. But then svchosts memory usage increased to several hundred MBs. Later it decreased but instead w3wp increased to ~5GB which lead to an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Thanks, but one large obstacle is that currently there are no unique row identifiers like a primary key. Altering and updating the existing tables is practically not an option at all. Do you think that the datareader is the problem? By now, I could imagine that the wcf service doesn't start streaming while the datareader is still open and reading rows. I tried setting `maxBufferPoolSize`and `maxBufferSize` to 100MB on service and client side but the memory stream still grows until 1GB.

Comment: But you can use Row_number in sql server query. I will try to explain it later. You have to think that the memory consumption its due to the datareader. Maxbuffersize, etc. are properties of the communication.

Comment: Although you haven't a row Identifier, you can do the pagination work too.I have reedited my answer.