# WCF - Stream from open SqlDataReader

Tags: .net, wcf, streaming, sqldatareader

In my service I've got a large SQL result set that I would like to stream. A while ago the exact same question has been asked [somewhere else](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/streaming-sql-data.2509487/) but there was no response. So I'm taking the freedom of quoting it:

> Within the service, I am reading all the data using a `SqlDataReader` and writing the data out to the return stream, and then returning the
>   stream. The problem with the above solution is that the service reads the
>   entire result set into the stream, and then returns the stream.
>
> What I would like to be able to do is return the underlying stream the `SqlDataReader` uses to the client, or return the stream to the client
>   while the `sqldatareader` is still pumping data into it within the
>   service. The behavior I would like to have is similar to the behavior you get
>   when you return a `FileStream` from a WCF Service. On the client, you
>   are immediately able to start accessing lines within the file
>   regardless of file size.

As you can imagine, buffering the whole result in my service leads to out of memory exceptions.

For clarification: I'm not trying to return the `SqlDataReader`, but I'm serializing rows to a Stream like this:

```
Public Shared Function DataReaderToExcelXml(ByRef dr As SqlDataReader) As Stream
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream
    Dim tw As New IO.StreamWriter(ms)

    For Each row As DbDataRecord In dr
            'Embed row in ExcelXml, detailed function omitted
            tw.write(row.toString()) 'row.toString is just a simplification
    End While

    tw.Flush()
    dr.Close()
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

    Return ms
End Function
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348590/A-replacement-for-MemoryStream

Comment: The out of memory exception does occur when the stream is doubled in size, so this might be the problem that leads to the exception. But I don't see how this could solve the high memory usage of my service that in fact occurs. That's why I want to use the WCF streaming mode in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this resource on streaming large data in WCF:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

and a more detailed Streaming example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751463%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Your best solution would likely be to break up your requests/fetches into smaller chunks.  However, if you can't do that you can build a streaming solution.  The documentation provides some examples and requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're saying. Sounds to me like you assume that I'm trying to return the SqlDataReader. I edited my question by adding code of the streaming function.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question.  Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I've already been through both resources without success. Streaming is enabled and works everywhere else, just not while the SqlDataReader is open. For more details on my WCF configuration and code see http://stackoverflow.com/q/28903449/4166885. I've opened this new question because my underlying problem is that streaming while the DataReader is open doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Would it be an option to kick of an async process that writes the XML locally and return a URI to the client to retrieve that resource when it's ready?

Comment: If by write locally you mean on the filesystem then no. The service has no access to the filesystem at all. Everything has to be buffered or streamed.